# For an SKSprite, is customAction actually the Update call?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Because of general psychosis, Apple put an `update()` call in `SKScene`, but they forgot to put an Update call in `SKSpriteNode`.

Now, as far as all our testing can determine,

In SpriteKit, just using a "customAction" on a sprite ***seems to be exactly the same*** as running something in `update` in the scene.

```
func teste() {

    let a = SKAction.customAction(withDuration: 5.0) { [weak self] node, elapsedTime in

        print("Honest to goodness, this is the run loop. I think.")
        print("\(self?.k) \(elapsedTime)")
        self?.k += 1
    }
    run(a)
}
```

I have scoured the documentation to no avail.

Does anyone know if it's really true that "customAction" indeed runs every frame?  Is it effectively and safely an Update call?

(Example: conceivably, there could be a horrific coincidence that they run it "every 1/60th" or something, and it's not really running on the same runloop as the scene.)

Or, since apparently it's really just Box2D, maybe someone can shed light on this from the Box2D milieu?

---

**Resolution of the issue:**

Thanks to Knight, we now know that using customAction "as the Update call" is *almost* the same as in the update call: it happens in the *second* phase of the run loop, which is immediately after the update phase.

{If you prefer to have it actually happen in the update phase, you would need to use the usual workaround in SpriteKit - just call your own update function in the game objects, from, the Update call apple provide in the scene.}

Comment: They did not forget to put an update call in SKSpriteNodes, Sprites do not need an update method.  Custom actions get called during the Action phase of the update cycle

Comment: "Custom actions get called during the Action phase of the update cycle" an excellent point, good one

Comment: ("Sprites do not need an update method" your comment is incredible old bean  :)  Consider any game engine, in Unity language: the "Update" call on every game object *is the primary reason the entire scripting concept exists!*  To program tanks, bullets, mario, or anything else is to write the Update call.)  {By all means, Apple have their interesting and admirable "action" concept where Apple "performs something over time" for you; but of course objects, just as scenes, need to access the run loop.}

Comment: an update method is a waste of CPU cycles calling a function that does not need to be called.  Sprite Kit is not a game engine, Sprite Kit is a toolkit.  You have actions to handle tanks, bullets, and mario, so there is no need to have an update function

Comment: Unity is very inefficient when it comes to game design, but the simplicity and ease of it makes it a powerful engine, since our hardware is powerful enough to compensate for the inefficiencies.

Comment: "an update method is a waste of CPU cycles calling a function that does not need to be called" ?  of course you only use it when needed.  Apple simply (for whatever reason) did not include it on >items< only on the >scene<. I believe you make an excellent point that the "metaphor" of SpriteKit is more a "tool" than a "game run loop".

Comment: if you have a 1000 sprites on screen calling a 1000 update methods that do nothing, you are wasting time.  just because you do not fill in the update method does not mean that in the background the update does not get called. If every node had an update method attached to it, then the system is either going to have to call the update method, or create a branch to check whether or not update was overrode.  Both of these methods would be time consuming.  It is a lot better to not have to do this on the back end, and let the developer create an update method for only the objects that are needed.

Comment: This is where gameplaykit comes in, where you can add an update component to attach to the sprites that need updates.  (It is possible that this is what unity and other engines do behind the scenes to increase efficiency,  I do not use unity enough to confirm this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All action happen in the action phase of the update cycle[image]

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skscene

Comment: Fantastic info.  TBC you mean the "second" item, labelled "SKScene evaluates actions".  So all `SKAction` are performed in there.

Comment: Yes, you do not have control of what goes on in that gray area, that is all behind the scenes, but as you can see, you have control before and after

Comment: Just to be crystal clear for anyone googling here:  **If we add a thing in SKAction.customAction** in fact that thing will be performed, in the "second" segment shown in that chart which is a blue gray color and is labelled "SKScene evaluates actions". Remembering that SKAction.**customAction** is specifically a system that let's "you" run something "every time".  (Apple's other SKAction concepts, "take care of" performing something for you - say, a specific movement - over time.)